# How to create constructor function Count?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Function count() return 1, 2, 3... How to create constructor function Count?

```
var count = new Count();
count(); // 1
count(); // 2
```

Comment: where is the count function code?

Comment: I'm afraid that's what the questioner wants us to write for him/her...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if so then let newbies do it for him

Comment: I'm not asking for me to write, I'm clue, because I do not understand how to make the counter value returned ... 
Maybe you can show where you can read about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Count() {
    var c = 1;
    return function() {
        return c++;
    }
};

var count = new Count(); // count is now a function that adds and returns
count(); // 1
count(); // 2
```

Comment: This will not work since the value of `c` will always be `1` when its called the next time.

Comment: @Aashray I think you’re wrong, `c` is saved inside the function scope: http://jsfiddle.net/YPn4v/

Comment: Oh didn't see the inner function. My bad.

Comment: You should mention that `Count` is no constructor, and should not be called with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Count() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.count = function() {
        return (this.x += 1);
    };
}

counter = new Count();
counter.count(); //1
counter.count(); //2
```

Comment: +1 for actual "constructor" approach, but you should put the `count` method on the prototype

Comment: @Bergi I would not complicate it more than necessary for someone who doesn't even know how to build simple constructor

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable globally:

`var counter=0;`

Create a function to return the value:

```
function count() {
  return ++counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor needs to return an object for the most part,
so returning a number in the constructor will just return the instance of that function,
not the number. You can explicitly return an object, however, so the closest you can get is:

```
;(function() {

    var count = 0;

    window.Count = function() {
        return new Number(count += 1);
    }
})()

var a = +new Count // 1
var b = +new Count // 2
```

Of course, you could just do:

```
window.count = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        return i += 1;
    }
})()

var a = count() // 1
var b = count() // 2
```

Which makes more sense in most cases.

Comment: new Number creates a number object,which is the only way to get a constructor to return a number, as it has to return an object. If you have a better solution, please share it.

Comment: Just don't use a constructor if you want to return a number.

Comment: That was my second suggestion, but as the question was "How to create constructor function Count", I figured I'd answer it.